# Comparing fixed effects regression and robust regression

Tags: regression, fixed-effects-model, robust

I have panel data on countries' renewable energy net generation (and installed capacity) over time.  I am regressing these dependent variables on various socioeconomic variables, as well as binary policy variables.  I have have done basic OLS, but I wanted to explore both fixed effects models, as there are likely significant country effects and robust regression, as Q-Q plots indicate that there are some strong outliers.  This might be a question of apples and oranges, but how do I compare the goodness of fit of the fixed effects models with the robust regression models?  One can use F-tests to compare OLS and the fixed effects, and since the OLS and robust regressions have the same number of DFs, looking at the residual standard error is insightful.